# Make a menu from nested hierarchical data or array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, menu, hierarchical-data

I want to make a menu, hierarchical data category. I can extract at the array but I must generate the menu. Here is what I have done:

[image]

```
Array (
    [17] => Array ( 
        [cat_id] => 17,
        [section_left] => 200,
        [section_right] => 211,
        [section_level] => 1,
        [section_name] => Bauturi,
        [nflag] => 1 ),
    [22] => Array ( 
        [cat_id] => 22,
        [section_left] => 201,
        [section_right] => 204,
        [section_level] => 2,
        [section_name] => Bere,
        [nlag] => 1 ),
    [32] => Array ( 
        [cat_id] => 32,
        [section_left] => 202,
        [section_right] => 203,
        [section_level] => 3,
        [section_name] => Fara Alool,
        [nflag] => 0 ),
    [31] => Array ( 
        [cat_id] => 31,
        [section_left] => 205,
        [section_right] => 210,
        [section_level] => 2,
        [section_name] => Cu Alcol,
        [nflag] => 1 ),
    [34] => Array ( 
        [cat_id] => 34,
        [section_left] => 206,
        [section_right] => 207,
        [section_level] => 3,
        [section_name] => Tuborg,
        [nflag] => 0 ),
    [58] => Array ( 
        [cat_id] => 58
        [section_left] => 208
        [section_right] => 209
        [section_level] => 3
        [section_name] => uuuu5 
        [nflag] => 0)
) 
Array ( 
    [18] => Array ( 
        [cat_id] => 18,
        [section_left] => 212,
        [section_right] => 219,
        [section_level] => 1,
        [section_name] => Patiserie,
        [nflag] => 1 ),
    [23] => Array ( 
        [cat_id] => 23,
        [section_left] => 213,
        [section_right] => 214,
        [section_level] => 2,
        [section_name] => Prajituri,
        [nflag] => 0 ),
    [24] => Array ( 
        [cat_id] => 24,
        [section_left] => 215,
        [section_right] => 218,
        [section_level] => 2,
        [section_name] => Ciocolata,
        [nflag] => 1 ),
    [33] => Array ( 
        [cat_id] => 33,
        [section_left] => 216,
        [section_right] => 217,
        [section_level] => 3,
        [section_name] => Beks,
        [nflg] => 0 )
)
.
.
.
```

With this code I obtain that menu, but I have a bug. I must get all the children and make a sub-down menu for each for example first item,

- `BAUTURI 1`
- `--BERE 2`
- `-----Fara Alcool 3`
- `--Cu alcool`
- `-----Tuborg 3`
- `-----uuuuu5 3`

My question is, how  can I build that foreach as for item in db to show correctly in the page?

Comment: Your array structure is unreadable. Please, format it and edit your post. Answering your so-far doubts, have you tried something? I suggest you research on [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Comment: Array scheme was edited !

Comment: You'll need a recursive function to do it. What have you tried? (if nothing, try a recursive function and bring it here so we can discuss it)